# Is there a way to re-start the Marketing Cloud Connector Wizard

Tags: marketing-cloud

**In Summary** - can I force the Marketing Cloud Connect configuration wizard to re-start from the beginning?

**Details:**
I am trying to configure Marketing Cloud and overall the entire process has been quite difficult and there seems to be a significant amount of assumed knowledge.

I got to the point where I was running the Marketing Cloud Connect configuration wizard, and it ran but only 1 configuration item was returned with a green tick. No other configuration items listed and no errors.

I clicked on from the screen too quickly, but from memory the only item was IP AllowList (I am fairly certain it was NOT the "IP Whitelisting" item as shown in all the how to guides.

Now, in hindsight I think there was maybe a couple of steps I had done in the wrong order and also I didn'd realise the configuration wizard must be run in Classic (?)

Now I am just presented with the page "Welcome to marketing cloud connector" - You're almost ready to connect!

If I click on the "Connect to Marketing Cloud" button I get an error

"Attempt to de-reference a null object"

The page also states
*Once complete, enter your Marketing Cloud API User's credentials and click Connect.*

However, I am unsure where I am meant to enter the credentials.

Additionally, under advanced settings there's a toggle for "Tenant-Specific OAuth Endpoints", I have not adjusted that and it's currently toggled OFF.

I feel like I perhaps just need to re-start the wizard from the beginning, but I don't know how. I just keep getting brough back to this page.

Is there a way I can force the wizard to restart?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just run into this same issue. I was not logged in as my connector user so I got that error message. What I did was this:

1. Log out
2. Log in as connector user
3. Go to the Marketing Cloud tab.
4. Click Show Advanced Settings.
5. Enable Tenant-Specific OAuth Endpoints.
6. Click ok

This will show the the wizard again.
I followed the wizard again and it solved the issue.

Hope this helps!